# How to opt out of Mac OS Catalina beta?

Tags: mac, macos-catalina

How can I opt out of Mac OS Catalina beta and get normal updates ? I had enrolled for the beta program a few months back and now I want to opt out of that. Specifically I want to use the new Sidecar feature.

Currently I am on Catalina Beta 10.15 (19A487l). But I cannot find the option to opt out of the beta program as mentioned in various sites.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

As it can be seen, there is no option under the settings image. 
Is there something else that I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like it is enrolled, the key data bottom left is missing - see [Apple KB: Unenroll Your Devices](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll) - but if you're stuck & it's not finding the current release Delta update, then try getting the [Combo Updater for 10.15.2](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2028) from Apple & see if that fixes it.

Comment: I will check when I get home